# swift - уменьшение fps при переходе с SKScene на UIViewController и назад

Tags: xcode, swift, protocol

Когда я перехожу с `GameScene`(`SKScene`) на `Market`(`UIViewController`) и назад  fps уменьшается, и сколько раз я делал такие переходы, он все уменьшается и уменьшается пока просто не вылетит из игры. Может кто-нибудь подсказать почему? Переход совершается через `delegate(protocol)`. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что делать?

```
//GameScene

import SpriteKit
protocol GameDelegate {
    func Market()
    func Question()
}
...
func returnToMarket(){
    self.viewController.Market()
}
// GameViewController

class GameViewController: UIViewController , GameDelegate{
    func Market() {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Market", bundle: nil)
        let vc : UIViewController =                 storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Market") 
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    ...

}

// Market(UIViewController)
func ReturnToMainMeny() {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController =   storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Проверьте allocations/leaks может где то память забивается

Comment: Можете пожалуйста немножко подробнее ?

Comment: В Xcode нажать command+i, и выбрать инструмент leaks. Там увидите memory allocations и leaks. В leaks xcode показывает какие утечки памяти он нашел - идеально не должно быть ни одной (обычно тут и там по 16-32 байта утекает). В memory allocations смотреть, что не происходит ничего необычного - например если вы открыли какой то экран, размер выделенной памяти увеличивается. Когда нажали back, контроллер должен удалиться из памяти, соответственно объем выделеной памяти должен вернуться примерно на тот же уровень, что и до открытия экрана.

Comment: Спасибо , что подсказал про это . Я когда открываю и на месте leaks начинает означать галочки и иксы , там где иксы это связано с утечкой ? , и в поле , внизу , выходят какие то тоже утечки , если я не так понял подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо ты мне очень помог , тут есть какие нибудь балы вам поставить или очки , просто не разбираюсь в вот этой программе

Comment: принять ответ если он решил проблему (галочка). :) а вообще можно на любом ответе нажать стрелку вверх если он пригодился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот примерная аннотация по Leaks:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]